# Image Assest for all device

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, autolayout

I have a storyboard file with **Width Any & height Any** AutoLayout.

I have a Imageview with **(0,0,0,0) constraint**

I want to show one Static Image. My app is supports both Landscape & Portrait mode with all iPhone & iPad.

So, **What should be size of Image View? Image should not be starched or compress**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 0):

You already stated the ImageView's constraints are 0/0/0/0, so its size will be adjusted depending on the device. Use **View Mode** setting in the ImageView's **Attributes Inspector** if you are not satisfied with how the image is looking on different devices - for a "background" image, which I suppose is your case, the **Aspect Fit** setting should be the most appropriate.